# What does the Meteor smart.lock file do?

Tags: meteor

What does the file smart.lock do for my meteor project? If I delete it from my project the app still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `smart.lock` file is used by meteorite to handle your app's dependencies:

> Meteorite writes to a smart.lock file in the app's root directory to
>   track the exact versions of its dependencies, even when it's set up in
>   a fresh environment.

From [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/meteorite). My original assumption about your problem was that you had no meteorite packages, which I was mistaken. Hubert points out in his comment that your project generally relies on smart.json and uses smart.lock as a cache (more info below), hence why the application continued to work on your own machine.

Comment: I have multiple packages, such as collectionFS and iron-router. I also have meteor specific packages listed on meteor docs like bootstrap and accounts.

Comment: The app will work when you remove `smart.lock` and it will be recreated after a while. The important information is in `smart.json`, `smart.lock` only acts as a cache so that the package metadata doesn't have to be pulled from the web each time.

Comment: @HubertOG thanks. I asked this question because when I zip up my meteor app and send it too a different computer to run locally it won't work. I was wondering if smart.lock had anything to do with it.